# pandas - Replace one letter in a string with its capital

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a columns with some names that need capitalizing in the middle of the word, like Mcgill to McGill, Mcneill to McNeill, O'donnell to O'Donnell, etc.

I know some text editors can do this by prepending the captured group with `\U` but this doesn't work in pandas.

Here's what I tried. Is this even possible?

```
import pandas as pd
names =  pd.Series(["Mcgill", "Mcneill", "O'donnell", "Mctavish"])

names.replace(r'\bMc([a-z])', r'Mc\U$1', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply()` in combination with `re.sub()`:

```
import pandas as pd, re
names = pd.Series(["Mcgill", "Mcneill", "O'donnell", "Mctavish"])

def capitalize(name):
    rx = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=Mc)|(?<=O\'))([a-z])')

    def repl(m):
        char = m.group(1)
        return char.upper()

    return rx.sub(repl,name)

names = names.apply(capitalize)  
# 0       McGill
# 1      McNeill
# 2    O'Donnell
# 3     McTavish
```

Is this what you were after?